# Querying items where ALL values match in a single column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, in-clause

I'm trying to get the results of a table where ALL the items match AND then only show the results where they all match within a specific stockId.

I've tried to do variantId IN (4,1,8) as an example, but it shows me all the results not where they ALL match 4 1 AND 8:

```
SELECT * FROM `products_bind_variant_stock_combination` 
WHERE `variantId` IN (4,1,8)
```

I'm expecting it to return either 3 results of where the variant Id match 4, 1 AND 8.  Or I want to show just the stock ID where the IDs match all of those.

My structure in

```
products_bind_variant_stock_combination


|subId        |int(10)|No |
|productsId   |int(10)|Yes|NULL
|stockId      |int(10)|Yes|NULL
|variantId    |int(10)|No |
```

A small sample is:

```
|1|69|1|4
|2|69|1|1
|3|69|1|8
|4|69|2|5
|5|69|2|1
|6|69|2|8
|7|69|3|6
|8|69|3|1
|9|69|3|8
```

The result I want when searching variantId as matching 4,1,8 is:

```
|1|69|1|4
|2|69|1|1
|3|69|1|8
```

Comment: Do you want a product with variantId values 1, 4, 8, 5 to be returned? Add that combination to your sample table data, and perhaps adjust the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), we can get all the `stockId` values which has only `1,4,8` `variantId` values. To find that, we can `GROUP BY` on `stockId` and using conditional aggregation based filtering in `HAVING` clause.

Now, we can Join back to the main table using `stockId` and get all the rows for that `stockId` value.

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM products_bind_variant_stock_combination AS t1
JOIN (SELECT stockID
      FROM products_bind_variant_stock_combination
      GROUP BY stockID 
      HAVING SUM(variantId = 1) AND /* has variantId = 1 */
             SUM(variantId = 4) AND /* has variantId = 4 */
             SUM(variantId = 8) AND /* has variantId = 8 */
             NOT SUM(variantId NOT IN (1,4,8)) /* no other variantId exists */
     ) AS t2 ON t2.stockId = t1.stockID
```

Comment: Worked great thanks

Answer (score 2):

use `group by` and `group_concat` to find out the stockId list first, then filter the table with the stockId list.

updated, solve ordering problem.

```
select * from `products_bind_variant_stock_combination`
where stockId in (select stockId 
                    from `products_bind_variant_stock_combination` 
                    group by stockId 
                    having group_concat(variantId order by stockId) = '1,4,8')
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Works great and is a simpler solution than I expected.

Comment: '4, 1, 8', what happens if you get '1, 4, 8', or '1, 8 ,4' etc

Comment: That's a good point actually, just realized the order can be different, though the query is nice and short.

Comment: @davesanchez for production data, I would not recommend this query. Because their may be a scenario where a `stockId` can have a large number of `variantId` values. `Group_Concat()` is limited by `group_concat_max_len` and in this case, the string generated after `Group_concat()` would be truncated and give wrong results. Also, as jarlh mentioned that `Order By` is also crucial in this query.

Comment: @yip102011 - Very clever adding in the ordering internally.  I like this solution alot too.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select * from products_bind_variant_stock_combination p
where 
  exists (select 1 from products_bind_variant_stock_combination p2 where p2.stockId = p.stockId and  variantId=1)
  and exists (select 1 from products_bind_variant_stock_combination  p2 where p2.stockId = p.stockId and variantId=4)
  and exists (select 1 from products_bind_variant_stock_combination  p2 where p2.stockId = p.stockId  and variantId=8);
```

which gives you all records with the same stockId, where other records with the other variantIds exist.